# How can I filter by multiple properties in artifactory using the java client?

Tags: properties, artifactory

```
Properties are for Guiding, not for Restricting
When you define a property-set with 'strongly-typed' property values, those values are used to provide an intuitive, guiding UI for tagging and locating items.

The actual value does not force a strong relationship to the original property-set's predefined values. This is by design, to not slow-down common repository operations and for keeping artifacts management simple by allowing properties to change and evolve freely over time, without worrying about breaking older property rules.

Properties are therefore a helpful and non-restrictive feature.
```

From this link: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties

Does this mean that artifactory doesn't restrict by properties in any way?
So if I have  the following:

file1.txt with properties a, b, c
file2.txt with properties a, b, e

And I search for files with properties 'b' and 'e' both files will be returned, because both files have property 'b', even though file1.txt doesn't have property 'e'?

I would like to be able to search by property and only return files with property 'b' and 'e'. Is that possible?

Or is the only solution to filter after the query?

I'm using the java client, and I don't know the file names before-hand, just a few properties.

Comment: I am not sure on java client but artifactory aql can be used for this and you can fetch files having both e and b in it -- as far as I my understanding is correct

Comment: Yes, just playing with that now. Using aql to make api queries via the java client is possible. Works as expected.

Comment: Cool. Missed the opportunity to answer :)

Comment: If you want to provide an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: nope..since you already got the answer by yourself...it would make more sense to you to answer and accept it..thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough :-) I'll get on that later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AQL to make queries via the java client. Searching for files based on properties is very fast and powerful. Once you find the files you want, THEN query those exact files instead.